# How to use Bootstrap editable field for Date picker?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

I would like to implement Datepicker in the Bootstrap editable field. Have already gone through their documentation.

```
        <tr>
            <td>
                <h5>Date of Birth</h5></td>
            <td>
                <h4>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter Date of Birth" class="editable editable-click dob">
                            <input class="form-control" id="dob" type="text" readonly />

                            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                        </div>

                    </div>

        </h4>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

All other editable fields are working well. I can save data onclick. However, Datepicker is not ever poping out.

Answer (score 2):

O! I have got the correct way of implementing this.

```
<tr>
                    <td>
                        <h5>Date of Birth</h5></td>
                    <td>
                        <h4>
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <div id="datepicker" class="input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy">
                                    <input class="form-control" id="dob" type="text" readonly />

                                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
                                    <a id="dob" class="date" data-type="date" data-pk="1" data-title="Enter Date of Birth" class="editable editable-click dob"> </a>

                                </div>

                            </div>

                </h4>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```